# Por que el Callback solo se llama una vez en la validación de un entry? Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, validación

Tengo un codigo python usando el modulo de Tkinter, el problema es que añadí una validación a un entry y el callback solo se ejecuta una vez, a pesar de que debería ejecutarse cada vez que ocurra un key event:

```
#Callback
def isNumber():
    print("Callback")

root=tk.Tk()

#Entry con la validacion 
entry1=tk.Entry(root, width=30, validate="key", validatecommand=(isNumber))     
entry1.pack(pady=20)

#Entry normal sin validación, solo para probar eventos de Foco
entry2=tk.Entry(root, width=10)
entry2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Output del código]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes que todo los controles como los cuadros de texto o un `tk.Entry`, requiere de una variable de cadena para modificar o evaluar una determinada función, por lo cual pasando una variable de cadena o un `tk.StringVar()` puede lograr que la función se ejecute de manera repetida ya que `validatecommand` solo llama la función una sola vez ya que no tiene una variable. Usando el método `trace()` en la variable, puede de alguna manera realizar un seguimiento a la validación al ejecutar `validatecommand` en el `tk.Entry`.

**Esta sería la solución:**

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()

entry1Var = tk.StringVar() # Variable de texto del cuadro de entrada

def isNumber(*args):
    print("Callback")


#Entry con la validacion 
entry1Var.trace("w", isNumber) # Evaluar la variable
entry1=tk.Entry(root, width=30, validate="key", validatecommand=(isNumber), textvariable=entry1Var)     
entry1.pack(pady=20)

#Entry normal sin validación, solo para probar eventos de Foco
entry2=tk.Entry(root, width=10)
entry2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Gracias, tambien me faltaba colocar el return del callback, pero tu comentario me ayudó a darme cuenta.